# Passing a value as parameter onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've started with learning React JS and I'm stuck at passing on parameters (such as a button id or Tab value etc.) to the Tab onClick event. I've been getting results back ranging from 'undefined'(when passing attribute name as parameter). 
Note: Tag is a component of material-ui library.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { value : 'a'};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);    //it prints undefined
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

<Tabs value={this.state.value}>

    <Tab label="Tab A" value="a" onClick={this.handleChange}>
      <div>
        <h2>Controllable Tab A</h2>
        <p>TAB A
        </p>
      </div>
    </Tab>

    <Tab label="Tab B" value="b" onClick={this.handleChange}>
      <div>
        <h2>Controllable Tab B</h2>
        <p>TAB B</p>
      </div>
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

I try to create a tab menu but I can't achieve pass the value of Tab to handleChange function. My aim is that, if the user click on the Tab A, this.state's value should update to 'a' in the other case the value should be 'b'.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry. **Tab is a component of material-ui library.

Comment: onClick={() => this.handleChange('b') is worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further inspection, I found the problem - you probably didn't inject `react-tab-event-plugin` because it's required by `material-ui` to make any `onClick`, `onChange`, etc. event fire. Also, your `render` does not seem correct to material-ui examples.

So, f.e., in your `App.js` comp., you should inject it like:

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

This component works perfectly for me:

```
state = {
   activeTab: 'a'
};

handleChange = (activeTab) => {
    this.setState({ activeTab});
};

render = () => (
    <Tabs
        value={this.state.activeTab}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
        <Tab label="Tab A" value="a">
            <div>
                <h2>Controllable Tab A</h2>
                <p>
                    Tabs are also controllable if you want to programmatically pass them their values.
                    This allows for more functionality in Tabs such as not
                    having any Tab selected or assigning them different values.
                </p>
            </div>
        </Tab>
        <Tab label="Tab B" value="b">
            <div>
                <h2>Controllable Tab B</h2>
                <p>
                    This is another example of a controllable tab. Remember, if you
                    use controllable Tabs, you need to give all of your tabs values or else
                    you wont be able to select them.
                </p>
            </div>
        </Tab>
    </Tabs>
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the code and wrote it, but I forgot to remove the letter A. Unfortunately that's not the problem, it's something else..

Comment: I updated my answer and explained the problem. Hope it helps you now :)

Answer (score 2):

Heyo, 
in this case you can use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) or you can pass the value using `this.handleChange.bind(this, "value")`